# Android - Is it possible to access raw capacitive input data?

Tags: java, android, mobile

Does the Android platform have a public API for accessing the raw capacitive data coming from the touch screen?

The multi-touch input points are derived from a basic two-dimensional grid of binary capacitive data from the touch screen. But is this data somehow accessible for use in an Android app?

Apparently iOS has a private API for this ([view here](https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/GraphicsServices/GSEvent.h)), but it would surely not pass the approval process. I'm hoping Android would be more open to this usage.

Comment: Definitely not at the SDK level. I cannot rule out the NDK having some means of getting this, or somehow getting it raw from the Linux kernel by one means or another.

Comment: See [Access Raw Touch Capacitance Matrix Nexus 5](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/115820/access-raw-touch-capacitance-matrix-nexus-5/147636)

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this question: this can be useful for further insight http://huyle.de/blog/capacitive-images/

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but maybe something to look further into.

Here are the kernel sources to various touch screen drivers. From scanning them a bit it doesn't seem that the kernel gives API access to this information,

https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/android-3.4/drivers/input/touchscreen/

Some devices seem to report "raw data", e.g. see `nexio_read_data` in [`usbtouchscreen.c`](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/android-3.4/drivers/input/touchscreen/usbtouchscreen.c) (seems oldschool IR type touch screen, not capacitive matrix)